# reactjs how to call method inside map function

Tags: reactjs

I can't make something as simple like that working.
It seems that the parser as a hard work to understand whats inside

```
 {[1, 2, 3].map((file, idx) =>
                  this.r_test()
              )}
```

Where r_test is defined like:

```
  r_test = (idx) => {
    <div className="input-field">
      <label className="active">Titre</label>
    </div>
  }
```

And if I write multiligne function, I need to use bracket inside. I know map is async and this is not my "this" as expected. But how can I deal and simply write instruction (loop + method call), without to have parser problem or scoping problem ? What is hard to me is js not throwing error but simply make it as a no op.

```
 {[1, 2, 3].map((file, idx) =>
                          {this.r_test()
                          this.r_test()
                          this.r_test()
}
                      )}
```

**edit**

What people suggested me is not working. calling this inside a map call didn't not work for me. The return missing was a typo, but that's still not make the call of the method. Worst, the parser is a nightmare to let write your callback inside a method + async map + others methods. What I finally done is a SYNCHRONE loop with an array in entry, and I return in the end the array with all the XML data.

for people who struggle like me, this is what I have done:

```
  r_aggregate = (qty) => {
    let elmt = []

    for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
      elmt.push(this.r_title())
    }
   return elmt
  }
```

r_title juste return some random XML. Don't look at the detail of the implementation.

```
 r_title = () => {
    return(
      <div className="input-field">
        <input spellCheck="false" value={this.state.title} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ title: e.target.value }) } id="input_000" type="text" className="validate"></input>
        <label className="active">Titre</label>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And now I can make my call with nested function call. What map is not able to do. The parser at least understand what I wrote:

```
 render() { 
...              
 {this.r_aggregate(3)}
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by `loop + method call `?

Comment: for i.... ++ < length {} in order to avoid an asynchronuous call. But I tryed what people suggested me and that's not working.

Answer (score 2):

In your map function, you are returning implicitly

```
 {[1, 2, 3].map((file, idx) =>    // implicit return since no `{}`
              this.r_test()
          )}
```

however you are not returning anything from r_test

```
r_test = (idx) => {
    <div className="input-field">
      <label className="active">Titre</label>
    </div>
  }
```

What you can do is

```
r_test = (idx) => {
   return  <div className="input-field">   // return explicitly
      <label className="active">Titre</label>
    </div>
  }
```

or

```
r_test = (idx) => (      //implicit return
    <div className="input-field">
      <label className="active">Titre</label>
    </div>
  )
```

when you don't return anything from `r_test`, you are essentially returning `undefined` from map

Comment: Man... Thank you! That look stupid what I said, but sometime return is required, sometimes it is implied depending on the context. I tryed everything except this simple return statemen. Those method what returning xml content on render() call, but not on map scope. Thank you again!

Comment: ah no :(.. That's not working on map scope. React parser has too much strange behavior

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from you `r_test`, right now you are implicitly returning `undefined`. Try this:

```
r_test = (idx) => (
  <div className="input-field">
    <label className="active">Titre</label>
  </div>
)
```

Note, I replaced `{` with `(`.